# code doesn't give desired output

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float f = 0.1;
    if (f == 0.1)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

OUTPUT:
    `False`

Why does it print `False` and not `True`?

Comment: I gave this a try and when f was specified as 0.1f, the result was as expected, can anyone explain why ?

Comment: @EricFortin You cannot rely on it. Just get lucky this time.

Comment: @EricFortin Suspect you also changed `if (f == 0.1f)` and that is why it compared.  Using `float f = 0.1;` or `float f = 0.1f;` should give the same result.

Comment: Here is a quiz for you. The program in your StackOverflow question is the first question in the quiz: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `!=` to check `float`!

The code is equal to check [`if (0.1f == 0.1)`](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz), as promotion and conversion rules mean that the comparison take place between double numbers. The decimal number 0.1 is represented differently as a single-precision float and as a double-precision double (and none of these two representations is exact), so when 0.1f is promoted to double, the result is quite a bit different from the double representing 0.1.

You should use

```
if (fabs(f-0.1) < 0.001)      // for 0.001, can be other suitable precisions
```

---

**P.S.:** To read on, check out [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: There is a simple explanation for the behavior observed, and this answer does not provide it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Updated with the explanation from the link you commented. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Typical floating point does not exactly represent numbers like 0.1 exactly.

`0.1` is a `double` and is only *nearly* the numeric value 0.1 - see below.  Assigning that to a `float` creates a further reduction in precision.

```
float f = 0.1;
// Convert 0.1 to a `double`.  closest double is     0.10000000000000000555
// Assigned that double to a float: closest float is 0.10000000149011611938
```

Finally comparing this to the high precision `double` version of 0.1 leads to a mis-match.

```
if (f == 0.1) // does not compare as equal
// compare f which is 0.10000000149011611938 to 
// 0.10000000000000000555 and they are not equal.
```

Example

```
volatile float f = 0.1;
printf("%.20f\n", f);
// 0.10000000149011611938
volatile double d = 0.1;
printf("%.20f\n", d);
// 0.10000000000000000555
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
if(f-0.1<=accuracy)
```

Comment: Need `fabs1` for absolute accuracy

Answer (score 1):

Do not use (in)equality for floating point numbers - They are stored as imprecise numbers - That is where the floating bit comes in

Write

```
if (fabsf(f - 0.1) < precision) ...
```

Where `precision` is the accuracy you require

See [fabs(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fabs)
and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)